# Socket.io Server does not answer clients

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-java-client

On the server, I changed the transport to websocket, and used socket.io-client.js as the client, and it worked.

> socket.io-client.js

```
{"GET":{"scheme":"ws","host":"113.14.15.178:3000","filename":"/socket.io/","query":{"EIO":"4","transport":"websocket"},"remote":{"Address":"113.14.15.178:3000"}}}
```

I'm having a problem, when the version uses socket.io-client.java on my Android application.
The server doesn't respond to requests when I use socket.io-client.java

> socket.io-client.java

```
{"GET":{"scheme":"ws","host":"113.14.15.178:3000","filename":"/socket.io/","query":{"EIO":"3","transport":"websocket"},"remote":{"Address":"113.14.15.178:3000"}}}
```

whether, the problem is with Engine.IO which is used in socket.IO-client. is there a solution for that

Comment: I would guess you have an incompatible version of `socket.io-client.java` based on the differing EIO parameter (which is Engine IO version).  You probably need a newer version of the socket.io Java client library that matches your server's protocol version.

Comment: have a reference to change version 4 on java client, or downgrade server to version 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've solved my own problem. if you are having the same problem. you can try the following:

1. add Websocket client module in your project

   `implementation 'blabla:ws:version'`
2. make the same query that comes out of the server header
    `ws.header({"filename":"/socket.io/"}).query({"EIO":"4","transport":"websocket"});`
3. check outgoing messages and incoming messages, from socket.io and websocket clients, when using webscocket-client.js.

example:

- input:40
- out:20
- input:30
- out:20
- input:30
- out:20

4. then do the same thing to make the condition true.
   `ws.open( (40) ? ws.send(20) : ws.reconection(); );
   ws.massage( if(30){ ws.send(20); } );`